# Fit data to normal distribution

Tags: matlab, gaussian, normal-distribution

I want some data to fit the corresponding Gaussian distribution.

The data is meant to be Gaussian already, but for some filtering reasons, they will not perfectly match the prescribed and expected Gaussian distribution. I therefore aim to reduce the existing scatter between data and desired distribution.

For example, my data fit the Gaussian distribution as follows (the expected mean value is 0 and the standard deviation 0.8):

[image]

[image]

The approximation is already decent, but I really want to crunch the still tangible scatter between simulated data and expected distribution.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**

Up to now, I have introducing kinda safety factor, defined as:

```
SF = expected_std/actual_std;
```

and then

```
new_data = SF*old_data;
```

This way the standard deviation matches the expected value, but this procedure looks quite poor from my understanding.

Comment: How is the data allowed to be manipulated?

Comment: The data embodies a certain power spectrum, that I'd like to conserve. as long as the power spectrum stays the same, the data can be "arbitrarily" manipulated to fit the expected normal distribution.

Comment: Do you have access to the Statistics Toolbox?

Comment: Modifying the standard deviation will not change anything in the normal probability plot. The "scatter" comes from the fact that your distribution is a little too "fat" (and at the tails, there's always the problem that you never get values of infinity).

Comment: @Jonas: you are right, I am already aware of the drawbacks implied by the process I'm currently using; that's why I stated that it's a poor method. And, again, you're right when talking about the shape of my distribution.

Comment: the tails issue cannot be completely avoided, but I believe that the data can be manipulated in such a way to better fit the expected normal distribution.

Comment: @fpe: modifying the standard deviation (you should modify the mean first, though) is a good way to bring your distribution closer to the real one. What I meant to say was that it won't affect the normal distribution plot

Comment: @fpe: If you want to modify the data, you will need to change the actual distribution, which means that the power spectrum will get distorted. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Jonas: well, the spectrum must stay the same because of some background I won't discuss now. The mean value is already approaching 0, the main issue is the std (I think).

Comment: @Jonas:btw, when I say that the spectrum must stay the same, I mean that its shape should stay close to a reference one.

Comment: @Jonas: how can I make use of non-linear transformation? Would you mind to shed a light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to make any non-linear transformations of the distributions, all you can do is adjust the mean and standard deviation.

```
%# 1. adjust the mean (do this even if the offset is small)
data = data - mean(data);

%# 2. adjust the standard deviation
data = data/std(data) * expected_SD;
```

Comment: but is not possible to proceed with a minimization process between the expected Gaussian distribution and the real data I have?

Comment: @fpe: so you would be happy applying non-linear transformations to your data?

Comment: We can give it a try and then I'll check if that implies any unwanted distorsion of the results I aim to have. Thanks for the support, btw :)

Comment: @fpe: sorry, am on the road at the moment.