# Histogram of lengths (or anything else physical) vs. counts

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have been searching a lot on the Histogram option `hist` in matlab, but I don't really find one suiting me.

I have two columns of data (in total 100 set of data):

```
x:     
     0 
0.0278 
0.0556 
0.0833
0.1111
0.1389
0.1667
0.1945
0.2222

y:
1
3
10
13          
28
53
66
91
137
```

As you can see, x is increasing approx 0.278 nm at a time (x is a length measured in nm). I would like to plot a histogram where x is on the x-axis (keeping the range from 0 nm to a total of 2.7503 nm), and y is the counts for every length, i.e. on the y-axis.

I have tried `hist(y,x)` but it gives me something completely nonsense (In the end, I know this is gonna be a Gaussian). I'm rather new to matlab, so this is probably something easy to solve, sorry.

Comment: I guess you posted a partial example, because that histogram look nothing like a normal.

Comment: Yeah I did, forgot to mention, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the counts stored in vector `y`, so you don't really need `hist` to actually count anything for you. I think you're looking for a simple bar plot:

```
bar(x, y)
```

Comment: Yeah that's it! Thanks! Btw.. do you know how to make a Gaussian fit to this plot I have by now? I want to be able to extract something like maximum point and width at half height for the analysis.

Comment: @NielsMøller Now that's a different issue, but a good place to start would be looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473064/fit-data-to-normal-distribution)...